# Bookdown preview_chapter

Tags: r, bookdown

I don't seem to be able to get `preview_chapter` working on my r bookdown project. This is my `_bookdown.yml` file:

```
book_filename: "thesis"
delete_merged_file: true
output_dir: "docs"
new_session: yes 

rmd_files: # defines the .Rmd files to be included for each output format
  html: ["index.Rmd", "02-methodology.Rmd", "03-results.Rmd", "99_references.Rmd"]
```

When I use:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", bookdown::'gitbook')
```

The entire book compiles correctly. But if I try to build a single chapter as follows:

```
 bookdown::preview_chapter("03-results.Rmd", bookdown::'gitbook')
```

I get:

```
Error in files2[[format]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

Am I using an incorrect syntax?

Comment: This is probably because the previous chunks have not been run, and as such the knitting environment does not have access to `files2`. You can test if this is true by trying to access that object in the respective chapter.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to have all my `.Rmd` files in an `.RProj` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. As long as your structure is preserved (and main files are in the same directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bookdown::'gitbook'` should be `'bookdown::gitbook'`.